# How to display only the current time

Tags: python, flask

I am calling an API that returns the current time fora certain time zone (estern in this case). It however returns me a lot of data that I dont need. How do I narrow it down to currentDateTime    "2019-11-07T20:38-05:00"?
here is my code;

```
import requests
import json
import jsonpath
import dateutil
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask import jsonify, make_response

# declaring app
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder="templates")

# app route defined
@app.route('/get_time', methods=['GET'])
def get_time():
    # error handling
    try:
        time_zone = request.args.get('time_zone')
        url = "http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/" + time_zone + "/now"
        r = requests.get(url)
    except Exception:
        return make_response(jsonify({"Error": "Some error message"}), 400)
    return r.json()
    # I could not figure out how to display only Current Date Time for this error handling scenario
    # If I do narrow it down the invalid time zone error is not displayed.

    # this will return error if condition not met
    if response.status_code != 200:
        print("Error on response")
        return response.status_code, response.text

# main app
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

here is what I am getting in return:

```
{
  "$id": "1", 
  "currentDateTime": "2019-11-07T20:38-05:00", 
  "currentFileTime": 132176327192699737, 
  "dayOfTheWeek": "Thursday", 
  "isDayLightSavingsTime": false, 
  "ordinalDate": "2019-311", 
  "serviceResponse": null, 
  "timeZoneName": "Eastern Standard Time", 
  "utcOffset": "-05:00:00"
}
```

Comment: The  output is in json/dictionary format. Try dictionary way of reading the output. something like output['currentDateTime'] should give you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like

```
return r.json()["currentDateTime"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the `reutrn`, let me know whether it is working or not.

```
return r.json()["currentDateTime"]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: TypeError

TypeError: 'Response' object is not subscriptable